# Ubuntu 20.04 - при загрузке черный экран

Tags: ubuntu

При загрузке черный экран, даже нет мигающего нижнего подчеркивания. Пробовал все методы, кроме переустановки(nomodeset, исправлял проблему с файлами(fsck /dev/sda1), драйвер переустанавливал(nvidia) ), загрузка только в recovery mode.

2 видеокарты: intel, nvidia geforce mx250
Ноутбук: asus vivobook (64 bit)
Операционки: Windows 10, ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Если есть загрузка в mode 2 - то я бы сделал вот что: 1) установил (или убедился, что уже установлен) ssh server. 2) при загрузке в "черный экран" подключился по сети к ноуту по ssh и посмотрел, что написано в dmesg. В зависимости от того, что там видно - можно думать дальше. Ну, и когда такие подробности будут - можно продублировать вопрос на лоре. Там, конечно, закидают ссаными тряпками, но могут что нить дельное посоветовать.

Comment: Попробуйте сменить ядро на то, которое используется в recovery. Возможно что проблема не конкретно в драйвере, а в совместимости версии драйвера, версии ядра и модели видеокарты. Открытый драйвер пробовали?

Comment: Да, пробовал xserver-xorg, тоже не грузит

Comment: Я конечно не знаю всех обстоятельств, но будь я на вашем месте, я бы просто попытался вспомнить все действия, которые привели к чёрному экрану, переустановил бы систему и больше так не делал :D

Answer (score 2):

Решение временное получилось странное. Выполнил следующее:
-Подключил электропитание
-Загрузился в recovery mode(в аварийном режиме ubuntu)
-Зашёл в терминал и ввёл nano /etc/default/grub
-В строке GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, вместо "quiet splash"  написал "quiet splash nomodeset " и сохранил
-Также в терминале прописал update-grub
-Перезагрузил